ETH sent but not credited
Please i need help,
I made a purchase of ETH on coinbase an it was successful and i made a withdrawal from Coinbase to my Bybit account which it showed successful but up till now the ETH transaction has not been credited to the account,
The transaction shows this text below
( Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed )
The transaction hash is below
0x4389f0cb74d67febc869718127ebf1aeb69aef3b315b207633400693c275aaa7
Destinated Bybit address that was supposed to receive the ETH below
0x45261b598ec2ffffb6e33af2daaeb414420328d8
The transaction amount was 605$
Please i need help i don't know what is causing this delaying and where my money is at right now.

It was an internal transaction that deposited 0.17424623 ETH at Nov-23-2024 02:11:11 PM UTC.
Shortly thereafter at transaction 0xa9a393991dd0166c12e129a0a431f5269302fa6db6e13d95ff8e71416b530e73 0.244107445776128 ETH were moved to Bybit hot wallet. You should contact Bybit customer support.

Thank you on this, please why was the ETH moved to Bybit hot wallet? And i hope this will be resolved cause I can't afford to lose the money

Side learning point: All transactions are traceable by anyone(s) within the blockchain. No need to contact the bank :D All cryptos have independent whatever-scanner tools and all access them using hashed transactions as you explained here

@DannyMilla Bybit is a centralized account. They may consolidate all funds in a couple of wallets for security reasons.

So meaning my ETH will be released back into my Bybit account After reaching out to bybit? Since my ETH was moved to bybit hot wallet they're to release my ETH.

@DannyMilla They received the ETH in an internal transaction. It should have been credited immediately. Some exchanges do not support internal transactions automatically, check the documentation where it should be clarified. You should have contacted their customer support and provide the transaction hash so they can resolve your issue. Don't wait if there have been more than 48 hours contact them as soon as possible.

Ok I've provided them the necessary information I'm waiting to get a good feedback from them
